# Почему не срабатывает функция animate?

Tags: javascript

Не срабатывает функция `animate()`, которая отвечает за скролл к нужной секции. Я как-то неправильно прописал код для `animate`?

```js
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const nav__links = document.querySelectorAll('.header__menu-link'),
    htmlEl = document.body.parentNode,
    bodyEl = document.body;

  nav__links.forEach(function (nav__links) {
    nav__links.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      const scrollAnchor = e.target.getAttribute('data-scroll'),
      scrollPoint = document.querySelector('section[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]').offsetTop - 28;

      bodyEl.animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPoint
    }, 500, function () {
      alert('done');
    });
      return false;
    })
  });

});
```

```css
.fixed-on-scroll,
.header {
  top: 0;
  height: 95px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transition: 1s; }


.header__navbar {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
      justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1120px;
  height: 95px; }

.header__logo {
  transition: 0.5s; }

.header__menu-list {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%; }
  .header__menu-list li {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
    height: 100%; }

.header__menu-link {
  font-family: 'Quicksand-Bold';
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.5s; }
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="header__navbar">
      <a href="#"><img class="header__logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Out logotype"></a>
      <ul class="header__menu-list">
        <li><a href="#" class="header__menu-link" data-scroll="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="header__menu-link" data-scroll="about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="header__menu-link" data-scroll="experience">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="header__menu-link" data-scroll="works">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="header__menu-link" data-scroll="contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="about" data-anchor="about">
  <div class="about__title">
    <h2>Intro</h2>
    <p>What I am all about.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="about__subtitle">
    <p>I'm Lorem Ipsum, orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      <br />
      <br> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="about__progress-list"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых: `animate` - это функция из *Jquery*. Каким образом вы её собрались применять без подключения *Jquery* - непонятно.

Во-вторых: здесь мало применять только на `body`, надо еще и на `html`.

В целом я подключил *Jquery* и заменил в коде `bodyEl` на `$("html, body")`. Работает. Как это применить в дальнейшем - смотрите сами

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const nav__links = document.querySelectorAll('.header__menu-link'),
    htmlEl = document.body.parentNode,
    bodyEl = document.body;

  nav__links.forEach(function (nav__links) {
    nav__links.addEventListener('click', function (e) {           
      const scrollAnchor = e.target.getAttribute('data-scroll'),
      scrollPoint = document.querySelector('section[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]').offsetTop - 28;

      $("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: scrollPoint       
    }, 500, function () {
      alert('done');
    });
      return false;
    })
  });

});
```

```css
.fixed-on-scroll,
.header {
  top: 0;
  height: 95px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transition: 1s; }


.header__navbar {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
      justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
      align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1120px;
  height: 95px; }

.header__logo {
  transition: 0.5s; }

.header__menu-list {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%; }
  .header__menu-list li {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
        align-items: center;
    height: 100%; }

.header__menu-link {
  font-family: 'Quicksand-Bold';
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #000;
  transition: 0.5s; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="header__navbar">
      <a href="#"><img class="header__logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Out logotype"></a>
      <ul class="header__menu-list">
        <li><a href="#" class="header__menu-link" data-scroll="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="header__menu-link" data-scroll="about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="header__menu-link" data-scroll="experience">Experience</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="header__menu-link" data-scroll="works">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="header__menu-link" data-scroll="contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
<section class="about" data-anchor="about">
  <div class="about__title">
    <h2>Intro</h2>
    <p>What I am all about.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="about__subtitle">
    <p>I'm Lorem Ipsum, orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
      <br />
      <br> Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="about__progress-list"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Да. Только что прочитал, про то, что это функция из jQuery, изначально наткнулся на эту функцию, где ни слова про jQ не было [mozila developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate)

Comment: @Bender ну да. Там нативная анимация. Вот только там написаны чёткие правила для её использования. Например при задании времени использования писать обязательно `duration`, И callback'ов там никаких нет. То есть вы ссылаетесь на один док, а animate используете от другого